# Moving already Drawn shape on html5 canvas

Tags: html, debugging, canvas, drag-and-drop, clipping

I'm having trouble keeping one object on my canvas. The initially drawn box rendered it in the correct position, but it disappears when I drag it:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    eraseAllButton = document.getElementById('eraseAllButton'),
    strokeStyleSelect = document.getElementById('strokeStyleSelect'),
    guidewireCheckbox = document.getElementById('guidewireCheckbox'),
    drawingSurfaceImageData,
    mousedown = {},
    rubberbandRect = {},
    dragging = false,
    guidewires = guidewireCheckbox.checked,
    w = 90, h = 90;
    count = 0;
    boxesXCo = 0;
    boxesYCo = 0;
    i = 0;

// Functions..........................................................
function drawGrid(color, stepx, stepy) {
   context.save()

   context.strokeStyle = color;
   context.lineWidth = 0.5;
   context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

   for (var i = stepx + 0.5; i < context.canvas.width; i += stepx) {
     context.beginPath();
     context.moveTo(i, 0);
     context.lineTo(i, context.canvas.height);
     context.stroke();
   }

   for (var i = stepy + 0.5; i < context.canvas.height; i += stepy) {
     context.beginPath();
     context.moveTo(0, i);
     context.lineTo(context.canvas.width, i);
     context.stroke();
   }

   context.restore();
}

function windowToCanvas(x, y) {
   var bbox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
   return { x: x - bbox.left * (canvas.width  / bbox.width),
            y: y - bbox.top  * (canvas.height / bbox.height) };
}

// Save and restore drawing surface...................................
function saveDrawingSurface() {
   drawingSurfaceImageData = context.getImageData(0, 0,
                             canvas.width,
                             canvas.height);
}

function restoreDrawingSurface() {
   context.putImageData(drawingSurfaceImageData, 0, 0);
}


function drawRubberbandShape(loc) {
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(mousedown.x, mousedown.y);
   //context.lineTo(loc.x, loc.y);

   context.stroke();
}

function updateRubberband(loc) {
   //updateRubberbandRectangle(loc);
   context.restore();
   drawRubberbandShape(loc);
}

// Guidewires.........................................................
function drawHorizontalLine (y) {
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(0,y+0.5);
   context.lineTo(context.canvas.width,y+0.5);
   context.stroke();
}

function drawVerticalLine (x) {
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(x+0.5,0);
   context.lineTo(x+0.5,context.canvas.height);
   context.stroke();
}

function drawGuidewires(x, y) {
   context.save();
   context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,230,0.4)';
   context.lineWidth = 0.5;
   drawVerticalLine(x);
   drawHorizontalLine(y);
   context.restore();
}

// Canvas event handlers..............................................
canvas.onmousedown = function (e) {
   var loc = windowToCanvas(e.clientX, e.clientY);

   e.preventDefault(); // prevent cursor change
   context.restore();
   saveDrawingSurface();
   mousedown.x = loc.x;
   mousedown.y = loc.y;
   dragging = true;
   if (i ==0)
   i++;
   else if(((mousedown.x<=(boxesXCo+w)&&(mousedown.x>=boxesXCo))&&
                  ((mousedown.y<=(boxesYCo+h)&&(mousedown.y>=boxesYCo)))))
   i--;

};

canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
   var loc; 

   if (dragging) {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent selections

      loc = windowToCanvas(e.clientX, e.clientY);
      restoreDrawingSurface();
      //updateRubberband(loc);

      if(guidewires) {
         drawGuidewires(loc.x, loc.y);
      }
   }

   if(((mousedown.x<=(boxesXCo+w)&&(mousedown.x>=boxesXCo))&&
                  ((mousedown.y<=(boxesYCo+h)&&(mousedown.y>=boxesYCo))))
   && (dragging)&&(i == 1 )){
         context.restore();
         restoreDrawingSurface();
         context.fillStyle = strokeStyleSelect.value;
         context.fillRect(e.clientX,e.clientY,w,h);


      };

   //Trying to implement moving shapes but need to store values of drawn objs

};

canvas.onmouseup = function (e) {
   loc = windowToCanvas(e.clientX, e.clientY);
   restoreDrawingSurface();
   updateRubberband(loc);
   dragging = false;


      if(i == 0);
      else {
         saveDrawingSurface();
      restoreDrawingSurface();
      context.fillRect(e.clientX,e.clientY, w, h);
      boxesXCo = e.clientX;
      boxesYCo = e.clientY;

      context.restore(); 
      i++;}

      /*else if(i == 1)
      {
         context.restore();
      }*/




   //context.fillRect(mousedown.x,mousedown.y,w,h,"FF0982");
};

// Controls event handlers.......................................

eraseAllButton.onclick = function (e) {
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   drawGrid('lightgray', 10, 10);
   saveDrawingSurface();
   count =0;
   context.restore();
};

strokeStyleSelect.onchange = function (e) {
   context.strokeStyle = strokeStyleSelect.value;
    context.fillStyle = strokeStyleSelect.value;
};

guidewireCheckbox.onchange = function (e) {
   guidewires = guidewireCheckbox.checked;
};

// Initialization................................................
context.strokeStyle = strokeStyleSelect.value;
context.fillStyle = strokeStyleSelect.value;
drawGrid('lightgray', 10, 10);


//context.fillRect(mousedown.x,mousedown.y,(mousedown.x+50),(mousedown.x+50),"FF0982");
//context.drawRect(mousedown.x-50,mousedown.y-50,mousedown.x+50,mousedown.y+50);
```

thanx again

Answer (score 0):

Rather than drawing to canvas on each mouse movement, use [window.requestFrameAnimation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) to draw constantly.

At a guess, I'd assume either the browser rendering is interfering or the coordinates are out but I can't run your code to make sure.

I've written some pseudo code that shows what I do for rendering things. You'll need to implement this for yourself, it won't run out of the box, it's just intended as a guide.

```
var Box = function() {
};
Box.prototype = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    draw: function (canvas) {
        // draw the item on the canvas
    }
};

var box = new Box();

window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    box.draw(canvas);
    window.requestAnimationFrame();
});

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (dragging) {
        box.x = e.clientX;
        box.y = e.clientY;
    }
}
```